# Using PHPUnit installed globally with Silex project

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I have global PHPUnit composer installation in

```
*~/.composer/vendor/phpunit*.
```

I want to use this installation to run tests from Silex application. Test files need to use project's `*vendor/autoload.php*` to load classes which will be tested at least, while global PHPUnit needs to load it's own `*~/.composer/vendor/autoload.php*.`

So in the project's tests I can't use PHPUnit autoloaded classes. So do I need to install PHPUnit to the project? But it looks like overkill while I have global PHPUnit. So, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHPunit tool will already take care of the autoloading of the globally installed classes. Just write your tests and assume every PHPunit class is available (they really are).